# Cannot run scheduled task off network

Tags: windows-8, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a scheduled task (multiple ones) that access an EXE stored on a network drive.  These tasks worked perfectly fine when stored locally.

I am using UNC to avoid mapped drive issues when selecting the action.
I also run as selected user with proper permission.  The username/password for the remote resource is the same as the current user.

I get an event ID 101 & 203 when trying to run the task with Additional Data: Error Value: 2147942402.